# can anyone help me with this in c?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {
    int x,y,z,a;
    char arr[221];
    char temp;

    printf ("Enter values: ");
    gets(arr);

    a = strlen(arr);
    x=a;
    while (x!=-1){
           printf("\n%s", &arr[x]);
           x--;
    }    
    getch ();
}
```

the output must be like this

sample inputs:

```
A
2
1
R
X
D
W
```

note: since A is the first entry to the stack, the stack should look like this:

```
W D X R 1 2 A
```

"A" is at the very far end of the array or the stack, it means that "A" is the first one to go out from the stack. Then it is followed by 2, 1, R, and so on...

Your output should look like this:

```
A
W D X R 1 2 

2
W D X R 1 

1
W D X R 

R
W D X 

X
W D 

D
W 

W
```

Comment: Use of `gets()` is strongly discouraged. `conio.h` is not part of standard.

Comment: some hint may help you  ASCII 65 to 122 are alphabet

Comment: `x=a-1` instead of `x=a` and `printf("\n%c", arr[x]);` instead of `printf("\n%s", &arr[x]);`

Comment: the output will be display on letters if i do this printf("\n%s", &arr[x]);

Comment: Get rid of `conio.h`, replace `getch()` with `getchar()`, replace `gets(arr)` with `fgets (arr, sizeof arr, stdin)`. Then work on your issues. See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Your source of learning C is crap. You are learning 1980s style C which is completely outdated. You should get a new source of learning ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x=a-1;
while (x!=-1){
       printf("\n%c", &arr[x]);
       x--;
}
```

use `x=a-1` and `%c` instead of `x=1` and `%s`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using `gets()` so the input must follow this format `A21RXDW`. that is a string. Only in this case the top of stack can have `'A'`.

Now

```
char input[100]={'\0'}; //best practice
scanf("%s",input);
int stack_top = strlen(input) - 1;
//iterate
while(stack_top >= 0){
    printf("%c\n", input[stack_top]);
    --stack_top;
}
```